# Change color of a MudBlazor button in a MudDataGrid row

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I have a simple MudDataGrid. Each row has a single MudButton in the last column:

```
<MudItem xs="12" sm="12" md="12">
    <MudDataGrid Items="@PickList.PickListLines" Class="py-8 my-8">
        <Columns>
            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.SalesOrderRef" Title="Sales Order"/>
            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.LineNumber" Title="Line"/>
            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.ProductCode" Title="Product" />
            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Quantity" Title="Qty" />
            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.ItemType" Title="Type"/>
            <TemplateColumn CellClass="d-flex justify-end">
                <CellTemplate>
                    <MudButton Size="Size.Large" Variant="@Variant.Filled" StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.DoNotDisturbOn" Color="@Color.Primary" OnClick="@(x => AddShortage(PickList.PickListId, context.Item.LineNumber))">Shortage</MudButton>
                </CellTemplate>
            </TemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MudDataGrid>
</MudItem>
```

The OnClick handler calls a function which makes an API call. Assuming that API call completes successfully, I want to be able to change the color of the button that was clicked. I can't figure out how to reference just the one button that was clicked in a table though.... Making the call it's easy because the button has context. Not sure how that translates coming back after the call....

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either have a `Color` property added to your class.

Or, use a List/Collection to store the identifier for the model when the button is clicked and get the `Color` based on whether it exists or not in the List.

```js
<MudDataGrid Items="@Elements.Take(4)">
    <Columns>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Number" Title="Nr" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Sign" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Name" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Position" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Molar" Title="Molar mass" />
        <TemplateColumn CellClass="d-flex justify-end">
            <CellTemplate>
                <MudButton Color="GetColor(context.Item.Number)" Size="Size.Large" Variant="@Variant.Filled" StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.DoNotDisturbOn" OnClick="@(x => AddShortage(context.Item.Position,context.Item.Number))">Shortage</MudButton>
            </CellTemplate>
        </TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</MudDataGrid>

@code { 
    List<int> _selectedButtons = new();

    Color GetColor(int itemNumber)
    {
        return _selectedButtons.Contains(itemNumber)? Color.Secondary: Color.Primary;
    }
    
    void AddShortage(int position,int itemNumber)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"pos:{position} number:{itemNumber}");
        if(_selectedButtons.Contains(itemNumber))
        {
            _selectedButtons.Remove(itemNumber);
        }
        else
        {
            _selectedButtons.Add(itemNumber);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<Element> Elements = new List<Element>();
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() => Elements = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Element>>("webapi/periodictable");
}
```

[MudBlazor Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cYwxPFPmyNtYCkYK)

Comment: This is great! I'll give this a go now and see how it looks. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, this is driving me mad now. I have implemented your solution, and from the watches and debugging I have done it appears to work perfectly. However, the button just will not change color! I have even changed the ternary expression into a simple assignment of buttonRef.Color = Color.Tertiary and it still doesn't reflect in the UI! I have added a watch to buttonRef.Color and can confirm the new value is assigned, but the button remains stubbornly red (my Primary color). Any guesses at all as to what is doing this?

Comment: Remove the default colour attribute for the button i.e. `Color="@Color.Primary"`

Comment: And then if you want a default color set for the buttons then you can loop through the dictionary in the `OnAfterRender` method and set them there.

Comment: Perfect! Well, nearly - it is now changing the button I clicked previous to the one I have just clicked, but at least they are changing color now! Don't know why I hadn't spotted this was removed in your solution - thanks for coming back to me

Comment: Ok, one last really weird issue with this. When I click my button, the event handler is triggered, and everything runs correctly. However the button doesn't change color. If I click anywhere else in the DataGrid component, the new color is then applied to the button! Not seen this before - anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: try adding a StateHasChanged after you change the color and/or clear cache. If this doesn't work then post another question with your setup.

Comment: StateHasChanged sorted it - thank you!